# Removing entries with duplicates in specific columns SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 columns: A B C. I only want rows that share the same value in col A but different values for both B and C.

```
1 | item1 | Jan | Amy
2 | item1 | Feb | Amy
3 | item2 | Mar | Bob
4 | item2 | Mar | Bill
5 | item3 | Apr | Charles
6 | item3 | May | Doug
7 | item4 | Jun | Felix
```

Out of the example above. I want it to show rows 5, 6 and 7.

Is there any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your need, this could be a way, with a single scan of the table:

```
with test(id, a, b, c) as
(
    select 1, 'item1', 'Jan', 'Amy' from dual union all
    select 2, 'item1', 'Feb', 'Amy' from dual union all
    select 3, 'item2', 'Mar', 'Bob' from dual union all
    select 4, 'item2', 'Mar', 'Bill' from dual union all
    select 5, 'item3', 'Apr', 'Charles' from dual union all
    select 6, 'item3', 'May', 'Doug' from dual union all
    select 7, 'item4', 'Jun', 'Felix' from dual
)
select id, a, b, c
from (
        select id, a, b, c,
               count(distinct b) over (partition by a) count_b,
               count(distinct c) over (partition by a) count_c,
               count(1)          over (partition by a) count_a
        from test
     )
where count_a = count_b
  and count_a = count_c
```

The result:

```
        ID A     B   C
---------- ----- --- -------
         5 item3 Apr Charles
         6 item3 May Doug
         7 item4 Jun Felix
```

Comment: The table I used was just an example. I don't know the exact values of the table. There's also a few thousand rows...

Comment: @Kuro I can't get the point... the `with` part is used to build an example, you have to use the `select` query on your table...

Comment: Oh I misunderstood and thought I had to build the table myself. But the select works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.a = t.a and
                        (t2.b = t.b or t2.c = t.c) and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

This assumes that a column uniquely identifies each row.  If you don't have one and the table doesn't have duplicates, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.a = t.a and
                        (t2.b = t.b or t2.c = t.c) and
                        not (t2.b = t.b and t2.c = t.c)
                 );
```